# Renomear um arquivo ao fazer um download

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso mudar o nome do arquivo em link direto como por exemplo http://meusite.com.br/file/374749482.mp4 de forma que quando o usuário efetuar o download o nome do arquivo seja enviado para o usuários mudando o nome do arquivo pegando o nome no caso da variável `$medias["nome"]` colocando o formato no final ficando `$medias["nome"].mp4`

Sendo que meu site esta em um lugar e o host de links diretos em outro servidor.

Comment: É php ou é um arquivo estático?

Comment: No caso seria o arquivo que e salvo no pc do usuário.

Comment: php quando digo é se a página `http://meusite.com.br/file/374749482.mp4` é gerada por php

Comment: Não no caso e uma URL direta com nome de diretório file e arquivo com nome 374749482.mp4 só que no caso o arquivo esta em um lugar e o site em outro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Usando o atributo download=""

Pode-se usar o atributo download no html em um link, por exemplo

```
<a download="media4.mp4" href="http://meusite.com.br/file/374749482.mp4">Download</a>
```

Se o download não for iniciado por um link, você pode criar um evento em javascript:

```
function download(url, nome) {
    var el = document.createElement("a");
        el.download = nome; //Define o nome
        el.href = url; //Define a url
        el.target = "_blank"; //Força abrir em uma nova janela
        el.className = "hide-link"; //Adiciona uma classe css pra ocultar

    document.body.appendChild(el);

    if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent("onclick");//Simula o click pra navegadores com suporte ao fireEvent
    } else {
        //Simula o click
        var evObj = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evObj.initEvent("click", true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }

    //Remove o link da página
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.removeChild(el);
    }, 100);
}
```

usando:

```
download("http://meusite.com.br/file/374749482.mp4", "media1.mp4");
```

css:

```
.hide-link {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
```

Não usei `display: none` (ou visibility) pois não sei se afeta o click, e usei `-9999px` com `position: absolute` pra evitar afetar outros elementos na página.

### Usando .htaccess

Se `media1.mp4` for o único nome que vai usar e o download for do arquivo estático, será necessário .htaccess (acaso use apache).

Para "renomear" você precisa do header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...;
```

O `attachment` irá força o download e o `filename` irá dar o nome do download, então crie na pasta `/file` o arquivo .htaccess e jogue o seguinte conteudo:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp4)$">
    Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=media1.mp4"
</FilesMatch>
```

### Usando php

Se a página for gerada por PHP, ou você precisar que o nome do arquivo seja dinâmico, você terá que usar PHP e `header`, por exemplo:

```
<?php
$nome    = 'media1.mp4'; //Altere o nome aqui
$arquivo = './file/374749482.mp4'; //Altere o nome aqui

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $nome . ';');
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

//É necessário informar o tamanho do arquivo pelo php
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($arquivo));

$handle = fopen($arquivo, 'rb');

while(false === feof($handle)) {
    echo fgets($handle, 1024);
}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: @Rodrigo vou adicionar mais um exemplo, mas bem que você poderia ter informado isto né? rs

Comment: Desculpe eu editei a pergunta para ficar de forma mais clara.

Comment: @Rodrigo veja se a edição da resposta lhe ajuda.

Comment: só não entendi onde e que e pra eu colocar essa parte download("http://meusite.com.br/file/374749482.mp4", "media1.mp4"); e no link ou na parte do js ?

Comment: @Rodrigo você entedeu errado, o exemplo com `download("http://meusite.com.br/file/374749482.mp4", "media1.mp4");` é pra ser usado em qualquer lugar que não for um link, se for um link use `<a download="media4.mp4" href="http://meusite.com.br/file/374749482.mp4">Download</a>`. É **como eu disse**: *Se o download **não** for iniciado por um link, você pode criar um evento em javascript*