# Como forçar download através de url remota para qualquer tipo de Arquivo

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso forçar o download via url remota para qualquer tipo de arquivo sendo a minha prioridade no caso forçar download de arquivos de media de vídeo online. Como por exemplo desta url em questão [Url de mencionada aqui](http://www.anistream.ga/videos/1352868579.mp4)

Desde já agradeço quem poder me ajudar.

Comment: Como assim forçar?

Comment: Forçar o download deste arquivo pois a url em questão abre um player online eu quero fazer no caso este link ao invés de abrir o player de vídeo que ele efetue download do arquivo em questão.

Comment: Por acaso isto nao lhe ajudou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80516/3635 ?

Comment: Infelismente não ficou bloqueando o download direto.

Comment: Rodrigo, quanto ao seu pedido aos moderadores, dê uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/14033).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer com HTML apenas, usando o atributo **download** na tag `<a>`.

`<a href="http://www.anistream.ga/videos/1352868579.mp4" download="http://www.anistream.ga/videos/1352868579.mp4">LINK</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar algo do tipo:

```
<?php
 $file_name = 'mov_bbb.mp4';
 $file_url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/' . $file_name;
 header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
 header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
 readfile($file_url);
 exit;
```

Testei e funcinou para mim, você apenas coloca o caminho do video e o `php` força o download dele, para que funcione e necessário que [fopen_wrappers](http://us.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) habilitado.

[Achei a resposta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531292/how-to-force-download-of-a-file)